# Bad screen redrawing in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with Oracle SQL Developer.  When I use it on a Windows Server 2003 machine, it works fine.  When I use it on my Windows 7 desktop, I get a lot of redraw problems in the query results grid when I scroll either horizontally or vertically, like so:

> Edit: ImageShack was the original image host for my screenshot, and it's no longer a valid url. Since my problem is fixed now, I can't repro this. The gist is that the client area of the result grids was repainted as gibberish during scrolling.

This makes it tricky to assess the results of your queries.  Clicking on the header and on individual cells causes it to then redraw properly, but it's goofy to not be able to just scroll normally.  Is there any way to fix this?  I am using the current version of SQL Developer 1.5.5 with the included JVM.

Comment: Same thing happened to me when I switched from XP to Vista. And not only with SQLDeveloper but with any ADF (Oracle's swing framework) applications also.

Comment: By the way, I have a NVIDEA video card. I don't know if it has anything to do with the problem...

Comment: Can you tell us what version of the JVM is included in SQL Developer 1.5.5? Java 5 doesn't play all that will visually on Vista/7, but the later releases of Java 6 do.

Comment: Hmmm.  1.5.0_06 is what it has bundled.  I shall try to get it to work with a 1.6 jre...  thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to turn off DirectDraw -- see http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/configuring-oracle-sql-developer-for-windows-7/, specifically the bit where they add the following to sqldeveloper.conf:

```
AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  I was skeptical because this was suggested just as a tip to get Aero working (which was also annoying, but not quite so much), but this seems to have done the trick nicely!

Comment: Works!! Path of sqldeveloper.conf is SQL_DEVELOPER_DIR\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf

Answer (score 29):

I couldn't even see the dropdown list when I clicked Tools. Here's what I did.

1. Click Tools
2. Try to locate Preferences by moving your mouse downwards starting from the Tools button.
3. When in Preferences, do the same in step 2 for the left side of the panel and try to locate Environment.
4. When in 'Environment', try to locate 'Look and Feel'. You won't be able to see the caption but it has these values: Windows | Oracle. You'll know you found it when you see a dropdown with an actual value of Oracle.
5. Change it to Windows.

That solved my problem.

To hell with these kinds of stupid problems.

Comment: I've accessed to preferences via Alt+T and ALT+P

Comment: Great answer, Hocam.

Answer (score 9):

I finally solved the problem:
Go to \sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf and add this line:

```
AddVMOption -Duser.language=en
```

The problem was de user language (in spanish do not works)

Comment: This works also for Turkish language.

Answer (score 6):

I finally solved the problem after many tries in windows 10. Oracle should fix this without tricks...

What I did:

Download lastest sqldeveloper 4.1.5 with JDK bundled.
Run sqldeveloper and import settings from previous install.
Close sqldeveloper, and go to USER\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper erasing config folders of older versions.

Modify file \sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin

Change this option value to true
**AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=true**

Comment line:

**#AddVMOption -Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true**

Add this options before IncludeConfFile sentence at then end:

**AddVMOption -Dsun.awt.keepWorkingSetOnMinimize=true**

**AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true**

And finally always start sqldeveloper with **sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\binsqldeveloper64W.exe**

And change sqldeveloper theme to "windows style".

Comment: Worked for me! At least the first times. I also performed the option that @david provided below as I also had the interface in spanish.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! I was just giving up... Jeff suggested this thread at https://twitter.com/kodyaz/status/1071073137524133889

Answer (score 3):

This problem still reproduces in 2015, I'm using W7, jdk version 1.8.0_40-b25 and sqldeveloper version  Version 4.1.0.18.

I had the same problem and nothing seems to help, not even [William Rose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621954/1776630), until, in my desperation, I put the `AddVMOption` from his answer in the last line of my `sqldeveloper.conf` file and Voila! It worked. It seems that somehow the option is shadowed if you put it at the begging.

Just wanting to add this bit of information, but I can't comment yet due to lack of reputation.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem with vista and win 7.

- just downloaded the latest sql developer 1.5.5 version **WITHOUT** jdk included
- exported my connections from the previously installed sql developer and
- deleted my installed version!
- then downloaded the JDK 1.6 update 16 from sun and installed it: http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp (32bit version! even if you have win x64. sql developer doesn't accept JDK x64!)
- then i unzipped the sql developer 1.5.5 i downloaded (without the jdk)

on first start sql developer asks you for the path to java jdk: given it the path that i installed the jdk 32bit from above and it now runs fine!

even without switching from aero to basic windows design and without redrawing-problems.

hope this helps you too...

Answer (score 1):

Just install old version Oracle SQL Developer 3.2.2 (3.2.20.09.87) and jdk-6u35-windows-x64.

That's how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I made this step after solved

Add or replace the attribute of the following config file.

```
..\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf

AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
```

[Turkish developer can see this site](http://www.blogkafem.net/2015/08/sql-developer-windows-7-kasma-ve-donma-sorununun-cozumu.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove or comment out the line below in sqldeveloper.conf:

```
# AddVMOption -Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true
```