# Bad screen redrawing in Oracle SQL Developer after statment with error

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.5.21 64bits on Win7 . When I try to execute a statment with an error, the output script panel just starts making glitches, and I need to restart the program. I have tried all solutions from [Bad screen redrawing in Oracle SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428217/bad-screen-redrawing-in-oracle-sql-developer), but nothing works.

[image: screenshot with error]

Comment: please post your solution as an answer, do not edit it into the question.